# Error in match.fun(FUN)

Tags: r

I have tried to find an answer to this but I have failed frequently. I have a dataframe with a column of strings. I want to count the number of characters in each entry of the column and replace the string column with the counts.

```
data[,29]=apply(data[,29],nchar())

Out[2]: Error in match.fun(FUN): argument "FUN" is missing, with no default   
Error in match.fun(FUN): argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several problems with the code.

First, `apply` operators on a matrix or `data.frame`. You probably meant to use `sapply` instead.

Second, `nchar()` calls `nchar` without any argument. You want `nchar` — i.e. the function name, without calling it (the calling will happen *inside* `sapply`):

```
data[, 29] = sapply(data[,29], nchar)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.frames` you need to specify the `MARGIN` parameter of `apply`, which means, wether you want to apply the funcion to the columns or the rows.

```
# Apply to rows
apply(data[,29],1,nchar)

## apply(X=data[,29],MARGIN=1,FUN=nchar)

# Apply to columns
apply(data[,29],2,nchar)
```